# How to draw a circle filled with lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas

I am using canvas to draw circles in flutter, is there any easy way to draw circles filled with lines?
PS:I know I can calculate each line's points then drawing lines in circle. But is there any simple method that can be implemented without calculation?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: CustomPAint with looping line will be easy I think, are you trying to get others way?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh looping lines still needs to calculate the lines coordinates, finally I figured it out with linear gradient

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an easy and ingenious solution without calculation.
That is creating a linear gradient filled in the circle.
give two colors for the start and end of the gradient.
give transparent to the start color.
give the actual line color to the end color.

```dart
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.color =Colors.red;
 paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

 paint.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
     start,
    //the line interval is 20
     Offset(start.dx + 20, start.dy),
     [
 //give transparent to start color, give actual line color to the end color 
      Colors. transparent,
      Colors.red
     ],
//The interval [0.0,0.9] is transparent, and the interval [0.9,1.0] is red. So it looks like drawing red lines
     [0.90, 1.0],
  //just repeat the gradient
     TileMode.repeated,
     null);
canvas.drawCircle(
         Offset(centerX, centerY),
         radius,
         paint);
```